# How to catch Back event in different browser without History?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm looking for away to trigger event in Angularjs app by the Back button in mobile browsers.
I know there are a lot of posts related to how to do it - but none of them is referring to the click event in particular - from what i've found - all the solutions works with the assumption that the URL has changed. I want to trigger actions in my app without any relation to the URL but the click on the Back button itself....

Comment: There is no event accessible in the window when user uses browser back button if that is what you are asking. There are window unload events but you need to be more specific about what it is you need to accomplish here

Comment: thanks....i need to close modal window when user press back WITHOUT navigating back to a different url...is it possible ?so the Back press will trigger the close modal...and no actually go back...

Comment: You would need to create your own history entry when the modal is shown so that you can use the `onpopstate` event to hide the modal when the back button is clicked. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for more information. Check the `popstate`/`pushstate` example down the page